# C++ Grammar production: class-head

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Below you'll find the definition of the grammar production *class-head* in [[class]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#1):

> *class-head:
>
>       class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> class-head-name
>   class-virt-specifier<sub>opt</sub> base-clause<sub>opt</sub>
>
>     class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>   base-clause<sub>opt</sub>*

At the end of the paragraph you'll find the following:

> A *class-specifier* whose *class-head* omits the *class-head-name*
>   defines an unnamed class. [ Note: An unnamed class thus can’t be
>   **final**. —end note ]

From the above, I gather that the grammar for a named class, i.e., a class with a *class-head-name*, is given by the first definition above, and the grammar for an unnamed class is given by the second definition.

A simple question: wouldn't be possible to replace both definitions above by the first one, simply by substituting *class-head-name* with *class-head-name<sub>opt</sub>* in it?

Or to be more clear. Wouldn't be possible to replace the definition above for *class-head* for the following?

*class-head:

     class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> class-head-name<sub>**opt**</sub> class-virt-specifier<sub>opt</sub> base-clause<sub>opt</sub>*

Comment: Then how would you specify *class-virt-specifier* must be omitted when *class-head-name* is not present?

Comment: @Praetorian That's exactly the case mentioned in the sentence shown above at the end of the paragraph. The Note says clearly that the _class-virt-specifier_ is not valid in this case.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Notes are non-normative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you did, then there would be ambiguity. `class final` could mean a named class called `final` or an unnamed class that uses `final` as the virtual specifier.

Because of how the grammar is defined, `class final` *always means* a class named `final`. The grammar is unambiguous. The bracketed notation is not normative text; it simply explains the *reason* for the two definitions.

Now, you *could* define the grammar a different way to achieve the same effect, by adding another term:

> class-head:
>
> class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> class-head-name-stuff<sub>opt</sub> base-clause<sub>opt</sub>
>
> class-head-name-stuff:
>
> class-head-name class-virt-specifier<sub>opt</sub>

Comment: Are you saying that the definition for _class-head_ at the end of my question **would be valid**, if the spec was written with `An unnamed class thus can’t be final.` instead of  `[Note: An unnamed class thus can’t be final. —end note]`?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso: Normative text can be used to determine what ambiguous grammar means, but that particular statement wouldn't really do that. You'd have to say the same thing in a different way. And quite frankly, it's easier to just make the grammar unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

> *class-head:*
>    *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> class-head-name<sub>opt</sub> class-virt-specifier<sub>opt</sub> base-clause<sub>opt</sub>*

, because that would allow *class-head* to be

> *class-key class-virt-specifier*

which is not allowed by the original.

Answer (score 0):

No, because then it would be possible to leave out *class-head-name* while still specifying *class-virt-specifier*.

The grammar for *class-virt-specifier* is:

> *class-virt-specifier*:
>     final

And as you mentioned, unnamed classes cannot be **final**.